# Unable to Access Firestore Document Within a Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

#### Issue: Type Error

I setup a Firestore Cloud Function to call from my Android app which is being called as expected, however I am unable to access a Firestore document from within the method and receiving a **TypeError** in the logs.

#### Attempted Solutions

1. `functions.firestore().document('qa/content/feeds/main/content/'+contentTitle)`
2. `functions.firestore().ref('qa/content/feeds/main/content/'+contentTitle)`

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const MAIN_FEED_TYPE = "MAIN";
const SAVED_FEED_TYPE = "SAVED";
const ARCHIVED_FEED_TYPE = "ARCHIVED";
const SAVE_USER_ACTION = "SAVE";
const ARCHIVE_USER_ACTION = "ARCHIVE";
const SAVED_PATH = "saved"
const ARCHIVED_PATH = "archived"

exports.updateQualityScore = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const environment = data.environment
    const feedType = data.feedType
    const action = data.action
    const contentTitle = data.contentTitle
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    var feedTypePath
    if (feedType === SAVED_FEED_TYPE) {
        feedTypePath = SAVED_PATH
    } else if (feedType === ARCHIVED_FEED_TYPE) {
        feedTypePath = ARCHIVED_PATH
    }

    admin.firestore().ref('qa/content/feeds/main/content/'+contentTitle)
        .get().then(function(doc) {
            console.log('Trigger fired on content: ' 
                +  contentTitle +  " | user: " + uid
                + " | action: " + action + ' | feedType: ' + feedType);
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
            return {
                status: 'Get content success.'
             }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            return {
                status: 'Get content error.'
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a ref() method.  Realtime Database does.  You're probably confusing the two.

With Firestore, you deal with collections and documents, and there are different methods to get a hold of collection and document references.  Maybe you meant to use the [doc()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Firestore#doc) method instead, like this?

```
admin.firestore().doc('qa/content/feeds/main/content/'+contentTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I'm used to the Android syntax so getting used to the Js switch. Your fix above helped with resolving the *TypeError*. Unfortunately, the function is returning a finished with **status code: 200** status without displaying the expected logs that the Document has been returned. I've updated my code above to reflect the current state of the function.

Comment: It's customary on Stack Overflow to not change the question to a different question after it's been asked.  By doing so, you immediately invalidate all the answers that may still be useful to others. If you have a new problem that's different than the first, please ask a new question,

Comment: I believe the question still remains the same as indicated by the unchanged title. I documented my question with the first issue that was broken (the *TypeError*) and how that was resolved in order to provide value to future readers as it appears there is more than one issue with my function.  The body of the function is unedited above as the goal remains to access the document.

Comment: That doesn't really change the fact that the update immediately invalidated the correct answer to the problem as described.  May I recommend that you undo your edits, accept this answer as correct, and ask a new question that describes your new problem?  Stack Overflow isn't a good forum for indefinite iteration like this.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your feedback. I've reverted the question and code to reflect the original issue of the **TypeError**, indicated the correct answer, and will work on the following issues further and create a fresh post if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry wrong answer.**

You need to pass credential when initializing app.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();
```

or

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>',
    clientEmail: 'foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

[initialize the sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)
[Quick Start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: This isn't necessary.  initializeApp takes no arguments in Cloud Functions to gain admin access to the project's databases and other resources.